# Passing a React component as an object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a reusable React component that accepts a data object as a prop.  One of the key value pairs on this data object is a full component.

How do I go about rendering this component from the data object.

I have a data object:

```
      const data = [
        {
          id: 0,
          iconDescription: "star",
          iconActive: StarBlue,
          iconDefault: StarGray,
          name: "Button One",
          title: "tab one",
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          iconDescription: "star",
          iconActive: StarBlue,
          iconDefault: StarGray,
          name: "Button Two",
          title: "tab two",
        },
      ];
```

In this example the `iconActive` key will be passed a React component, for example:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
export const StarBlue = ({ fill, strokeWidth, width, height }) => {
  const rectangleSize = {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  };
  return (
    <svg
      data-testid="star-icon-blue"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
      fill={fill}
      height={height}
      width={width}
    >
      <g data-name="Layer 2">
        <g data-name="star">
          <rect
            width={rectangleSize.width}
            height={rectangleSize.height}
            transform="rotate(90 12 12)"
            opacity="0"
          />
          <path
            fill="#0078d3"
            d="M17.56 21a1 1 0 0 1-.46-.11L12 18.22l-5.1 2.67a1 1 0 0 1-1.45-1.06l1-5.63-4.12-4a1 1 0 0 1-.25-1 1 1 0 0 1 .81-.68l5.7-.83 2.51-5.13a1 1 0 0 1 1.8 0l2.54 5.12 5.7.83a1 1 0 0 1 .81.68 1 1 0 0 1-.25 1l-4.12 4 1 5.63a1 1 0 0 1-.4 1 1 1 0 0 1-.62.18z"
          />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
};
export default StarBlue;
```

Now I have a component which gets passed my data object:

```
        <div data-testid="app-component-container" className="App">
          <TabGroup tabs={data} />
        </div>
```

And I am trying to update the `TabGroup` component to render the `iconActive` component when necessary.
I have tried mapping over the data object `data.map((tab)=> (<div>{tab.iconActive}</div>))` but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Try `iconActive: () => <StarBlue />,` and then `tab.iconActive()`

Comment: Just do `<tab.iconActive />` Or you can use the long way: `tab => { const Icon = tab.iconActive; return <div><Icon />...</div>; }`